# Как задать уникальное название файла или папки при загрузке в Chrome (selenium - python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, pytest

Суть проблемы: есть тест, который работает в связке pytest-selenium-chrome, в процессе которого выполняется сохранение файла и его последующее открытие и проверка (все в headless mode). Для Хрома задана опция:

```
"download.default_directory": r"" + dwnld_path + ""
```

На текущий момент я определяю самый "свежий" файл и проверяю его, НО возникают следующие проблемы:

1. если в процессе выполнения файл не был создан, то берется файл от прошлого теста
2. если тесты исполняются параллельно, то нет 100% уверенности в том, что самый новый файл именно от этого теста.

Отсюда вопросы:

1. Есть ли возможность изменения имени файла в процессе его сохранения средствами chromedriver?
2. или может быть есть какой то другой способ решения моей задачи?

Была идея создавать временную папку для сохранения файла для каждого теста и смотреть ее, но браузер инициализируется единожды при старте и, как я понимаю, ChromeOptions в процессе уже переопределять нельзя.

Может кто сталкивался со схожей проблемой? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Варианты: добавлять текущее время / добавлять номер теста / добавлять uuid (guid)

Comment: Проблема в том, как изменить название файла ДО того, как он будет сохранен на диск. По аналогии - когда скачиваем файл, то указываем его название, а только потом - сохраняем. Был вариант еще получать список файлов в директории до сохранения, сохранять файл, получать новый список и сравнивать со старым, тем самым выцепляя новый файл, но этот вариант не работает, если тесты выполняются параллельно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Советую посмотреть в сторону создания небольшого расширения для Chrome, использующего [chrome.downloads API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) и работы с этим расширением.

Там есть очень интересная callback функция:

> **onDeterminingFilename**
>   During the filename determination process, extensions will be given the opportunity to override the target DownloadItem.filename. Each extension may not register more than one listener for this event.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910774/how-to-get-a-list-of-downloads-using-the-chrome-downloads-api) есть код расширения, использующего chrome.downloads API.

2. Далее нужно загрузить расширение при работе с Selenium.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511384/using-extensions-with-selenium-python) есть пример.

3. Открываем расширение в отдельном Tab браузера

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557533/open-a-chrome-extension-through-selenium-webdriver-using-python) есть пример.

4. Взаимодействуем с расширением из Selenium через данный Tab. Вплоть до выполнения его JS функций напрямую